# column aliases in postgres for calculated values

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, alias

I tried to uses aliases in postgres for this query, but postgres stops and complains that ERROR: column "subtotal" does not exist

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS subtotal, 
       subtotal * 3.0 AS fees,
       (subtotal + fees) AS total
  FROM cart
```

You cannot use aliases as part of your next column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can not re-use a column alias within the same SQL statement - use:

```
SELECT SUM(t.price) AS subtotal,
       SUM(t.price) * 3.0 AS fees,
       SUM(t.price + fees) AS total
  FROM CART t
```

You can reference the column alias in the ORDER BY clause, some databases also support referencing in the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Question about your answer:

```
    SELECT SUM(t.price) AS subtotal,
      SUM(t.price) * 3.0 AS fees,
      SUM(t.price + fees) AS total
    FROM CART t
```

Should it not be the following if you can not re-use a column alias within the same SQL statement:

```
   SELECT SUM(t.price) AS subtotal,
     SUM(t.price) * 3.0 AS fees,
     SUM(t.price + (t.price * 3.0)) AS total
   FROM CART t
```